# How to handle SignalR implementation under LoadBalancer Environment

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am fairly new to signalr concepts. I have a scenario where load balancing is in place with two servers. The situation is that client request is taken by the load balancer and redirects it to a one of the server based on the load. After redirection the connection from client to the server is lost. Important thing here is that client request is for different purposes i.e they call different methods on the hub. The server continues processing the request further and during this time if it detects any status change, it has to push the notification back to the clients. However at this point, server won't be knowing to which client it has to respond back as the load balancer doesn't store  any information about the same once the connection is lost from client to server. How to handle this kind of scenario?. Should I be manually storing session id and other details in a table?

I have gone through the scaleout options suggested for load balancing using backplane by the signalr team(Azure service bus,  Redis and SQL Server). However my scenario is little different. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You may have to be a bit more specific about the tech in your setup.

Comment: Hi Loofer, let me explain a scenario. Lets say C1, C2, C3 and C4 are the clients and S1 and S2 are the servers. Lets say our hub has services Svc1 and SVC2. Lets say C1 and C2  requests for Svc1. C3 and C4 requests for Svc2. Lets assume load balancer redirects C1, C2 to S1 and C3,C4 to S2. After this redirection the connection is lost between server and the client.Lets say S1 during processing notices a state change and pushes the notification back to the load balancer. How does load balancer has to understand this push notification has to be sent to only C1 or C2 and not for C3 and C4?